# Increasing the size of a spriteNode using spriteKit in update function (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode

I'm having troubles with animations, physics and stuff like these.

Anyway, what I'm trying to do is creating a pulsing effect for a sphere where the pulse itself is able to collide with elements on the screen, so I created another spriteNode (child of the sphere) that I want to scale continuously, without depending on touches.

I read that in these cases is better not to use SKActions.

My question is: how do I scale or increase the size of a spriteNode via update function?

The code represents how I worked so far for movement for example.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

 var entities = [GKEntity]()
 var graphs = [String: GKGraph]()

 var movingSquareLv1 = SKSpriteNode()
 var pulsingSphereLv2 = SKSpriteNode()

 var lv2SpherePulse = SKSpriteNode()


 var xVeloicty: CGFloat = 100


 override func sceneDidLoad() {

  movingSquareLv1 = self.childNode(withName: "movingSquare") as!SKSpriteNode
  movingSquareLv1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: movingSquareLv1.size)
  movingSquareLv1.physicsBody ? .affectedByGravity = false

  pulsingSphereLv2 = self.childNode(withName: "pulsingSphere") as!SKSpriteNode
  pulsingSphereLv2.physicsBody ? .affectedByGravity = false

  lv2SpherePulse = pulsingSphereLv2.childNode(withName: "lv2SpherePulse") as!SKSpriteNode
  lv2SpherePulse.physicsBody ? .affectedByGravity = false


 }


 func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {

 }

 func touchMoved(toPoint pos: CGPoint) {

 }

 func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {

 }

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {

  for t in touches {
   self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location( in: self))
  }
 }

 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {
  for t in touches {
   self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location( in: self))
  }
 }

 override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {
  for t in touches {
   self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location( in: self))
  }
 }

 override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set < UITouch > , with event: UIEvent ? ) {
  for t in touches {
   self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location( in: self))
  }
 }


 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

  rectMovement()


 }

 func rectMovement() {

  if movingSquareLv1.frame.maxX >= self.size.width / 2 {

   xVeloicty = -100

  } else if movingSquareLv1.frame.minX <= -self.size.width / 2 {
   xVeloicty = 100
  }

  let rate: CGFloat = 0.5
  let relativeVelocity: CGVector = CGVector(dx: xVeloicty - movingSquareLv1.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: 0)
  movingSquareLv1.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: movingSquareLv1.physicsBody!.velocity.dx + relativeVelocity.dx * rate, dy: 0)

 }

}
```

This is the object composed of two sprites, the one I want to work on is the largest one.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you add the code where you're attempting to do this? Right  now is very difficult to answer your question

Comment: If you want to have a circular collision, you should use skshapenode, since spritenodes have only rectangle collisions.

Comment: @AlexandruVasiliu I’m pretty sure that circular physics bodies are available and are recommended where possible as the most efficient shape for collisions and contacts.

Comment: I was refering at basic spritekit collision via intersect, not at physics body collision.

Comment: I will edit the post, I'll add the code and the sprites I have. Oh and anyway, I can work even with spriteNodes, I only have to use circular physicBody

Comment: @AlexandruVasiliu SKShapeNode does not offer path intersection on its body,  and there is no frame property to intersect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever told you to not use SKActions is wrong.  This is exactly when you want to use an SKAction, and if you have multiple circles pulsing, you use the same action on all circles.

You really want to keep your update function as small as possible.  Trust in apple’s optimizations because they have better access to the API than you do.

Comment: I would also agree with this.  Once you get the hang of actions and physics, you'll probably find that most of your game is just letting the simulation run along on its own.

Comment: Thank you both guys, I'm working with SKActions and it's going fine.

Comment: yes, the thing you do not want is to have SKActions on your scene that are not running.  If you have say 500 circles, and only 1 rotates, you do not want to have 500 rotate actions going with 499 of them paused.  Perhaps the person telling you to not use SKActions was misinterpreting that recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why whatever you read said that actions aren't appropriate, but if you want to change a node's size from `update` explicitly, then you can set its scaling.

```swift
myNode.setScale(2.5)  // 2.5x as big as normal
myNode.setScale(0.5)  // half size

myNode.xScale = 1.5
myNode.yScale = myNode.xScale * 2  // Set x and y separately for non-uniform scaling
```

See the documentation in the "Scaling and Rotation" section of `SKNode`:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode